# Software engineering with Ada: stubs; separate and compilation units

Tags: compilation, ada, stub

I'm with a mechanical engineering background but I'm interested to learn good software engineering practice with Ada. I have a few queries.

Q1. If I understand correctly then someone can just write a package specification (ads) file, compile it and then compile the main program which is using the package. Later on, when one knows what to include in the package body then the latter can be written and compiled. Afterwards, the main program can now be run. I've tried this and I would like to confirm that this is good practice.

Q2. My second question is about stubs (sub-units) and the use of SEPARATE. Say I have a main program as follows:

```
    WITH Ada.Float_Text_IO;
    WITH Ada.Text_IO;
    WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

    PROCEDURE TEST2 IS
    A,B      : FLOAT;
    N        : INTEGER;

    PROCEDURE INPUT(A,B: OUT FLOAT; N: OUT INTEGER) IS SEPARATE;

    BEGIN -- main program
      INPUT(A,B,N);
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put(Item => A);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => N);
    END TEST2;
```

Then I have the procedure INPUT in a separate file:

```
separate(TEST2)
PROCEDURE INPUT(A,B: OUT FLOAT; N: OUT INTEGER) IS
   BEGIN
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get(Item => A);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get(Item => B);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => N);
   END INPUT;
```

My questions:

a) AdaGIDE suggests me to save the the INPUT procedure file as input.adb. But then on compiling the main program test2, I get the warning:

```
warning: subunit "TEST2.INPUT" in file "test2-input.adb" not found
cannot generate code for file test2.adb (missing subunits)
```

To AdaGIDE, this is more of an error as the above warnings come before the message:

```
Compiling...
Done--error detected
```

So I renamed the input.adb file to test2-input.adb as was suggested to me by AdaGIDE on compiling. Now on compiling the main file, I don't have any warnings. My question now is if it's ok to write

```
PROCEDURE INPUT(A,B: OUT FLOAT; N: OUT INTEGER) IS
```

as I did in the sub-unit file test2-input.adb or is it better to write a more descriptive term like

```
PROCEDURE TEST2-INPUT(A,B: OUT FLOAT; N: OUT INTEGER) IS
```

to emphasize that procedure input has a parent procedure test2 ? This thought follows from AdaGIDE hinting me about test2-input.adb as I mentioned above.

b) My next question:

If I understand well the compilation order, then I should compile the main file test2.adb first and then the stub test2-input.adb . On compiling the stub I get the error message:

```
cannot generate code for file test2-input.adb (subunit)
Done--error detected
```

However, I can now do the binding and linking for test2.adb and run the program .

I would like to know if I did wrong by trying to compile the stub test2-input.adb or should it not be compiled?

Q3. What is the use of having subunits? Is it just to break a large program into smaller parts? I know an error arises if one doesn't put any statements between BEGIN and END in the subunit. So this means that one always has to put a statement there. And if one wants to write the statements later, one can always put a NULL statement between between BEGIN and END in the subunit and comes back to the latter at a later time. Is this how software engineering is done in practice?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I'm curious about the choice of Ada. Was this based on job/client requirements? Language stats (e.g. http://www.langpop.com/) indicate that it's not quite the language of choice for most projects.

Comment: Well, I know a few languages like Basic, Pascal, C and Matlab (if this one can be considered as a programming language). I have decided to learn Ada as being a strongly typed language it helps to avoid mistakes that can easily creep into other languages that I've learned before. And Ada promotes good software engineering practice. I can't find a better programming language. C can be faster but maybe harder to maintain than verbose Ada. I choose Ada not because of speed of execution but I want accurate results and its separate compilation units helps a lot when developing a large program.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: You have an excellent grasp of Ada's benefits and contributions to software quality and productivity. And actually, its performance is none too shabby either: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_thread/thread/847751a7e7aa6234?pli=1

Comment: Thanks Marc for your comment. I had to go through several textbooks before I started to understand software engineering methodology in Ada.

Comment: @Peter Rowell - That attitude is all fine and good, if your goal is to be at least as good as everyone else. If instead you want to be **better**, you won't get there by doing what everybody else does. You have to look for tools that can give you an edge.

Comment: @T.E.D. - there are a number of errors/fallacies to your argument: 1) That there was any "attitude" in my question; 2) that ADA programs are inherently better deisgned/engineered than those written in Language X, 3) that being skilled in ADA will given him any "edge" at all in the current economy. I've literally lost count of the number of languages I've work in over the last 35+ years, but the one constant I've found is that "good engineering" is more a state of mind and discipline than any particular language. FWIW, based on long experience, my current language of choice is Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1: That is *excellent* practice.

And by treating the package specification as a *specification*, you can provide it to other developers so that they will know how to interface to your code.

Q2: I believe that AdaGIDE actually uses the GNAT compiler for all compilation, so it's actually GNAT that is in charge of the acceptable filenames.  (This can be configured, but unless you have a very compelling reason to do so, it is far simpler to simply go with GNAT/AdaGIDE's file naming conventions.) More pertinent to your question, though, there's no strong reason to include the parent unit as part of the separate unit's name. But see the answer to Q3...

Q3: Subunits were introduced with the first version of Ada--Ada 83--in part to help modularize code, and allow for deferred development and compilation. However, Ada software development practice has pretty much abandoned the use of subunits, all the procedure/function/task/etc bodies are simply all maintained in the body of the package. They are still used in some areas, like if a platform-specific version of subprogram may be needed, but for the most part they're rarely used. It leaves fewer files to keep track of, and keeps the implementation code of a package all together. So I strongly recommend you simply ignore the subunit capabilities and place all your implementation code in package bodies.

Comment: Thanks for the insights especially for Q3. I'm using AdaGIDE with the AdaCore GNAT compiler. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty normal to split a problem up into component parts (packages), each supporting a different aspect. If you've learnt Ada, it'd be normal to write the specs of the packages first, argue (perhaps with yourself) why that's the right design, and then implement them. And this would be normal, I think, in any language that supports specs and bodies - for example, C.

Personally I would do check compilations as I went, just to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid.

As for separates - one (not very good) reason is to reduce clutter, to stop the unit getting too long. Another reason (for a code generator I wrote) was so that the code generator didn't need to worry about preserving developers' hand-written code in the UML model; all code bodies were separates. A third might be for environment-dependent implementation (eg, Windows vs Unix), where you'd let the compiler see a different version of the separate body for each environment (people normally use library packages for this, though).

Compilers have their own rules about file names, and what order things can be compiled in. When GNAT sees

```
procedure Foo is
   procedure Bar is separate;
```

it expects to find Foo's body in a file named `foo.adb` and Bar's body in `foo-bar.adb` (you can, I believe, tell it different - `gnatmake`'s package `Naming` - but it's probably not worth the trouble). It's best to go with the flow here;

```
separate (Foo)
procedure Bar is
```

is clear enough.

You can compile `foo-bar.adb`, and that will do a full analysis and catch almost all errors in the code; but GNAT can't generate code for this on its own. Instead, when you compile `foo.adb` it includes all the separate bodies in the one generated object file. It certainly isn't *wrong* to do this.

With GNAT, there's no need to worry about compilation order, you can compile in any order you like. But it's best to use `gnatmake` and let the computer take the strain!

Comment: Thanks for all the precious comments. I just want to confirm again that compiling a stub on its own will generate an error message as I got but it's ok. The important thing of course is to compile the main program and having no errors then. 1 vote up.

Comment: Simon, your answer is indeed very helpful but Marc's answer is a little more complete than yours. This is why I'm accepting his answer. Hope this is ok with you. I have also given you both 1 vote up for helping me, a novice, to learn better software engineering practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed work the way you describe, except of course your program won't link until all of the package bodies have some kind of implementation. For that reason, I think it is more normal to write a dummy package body with all procedures implemented as:

```
begin
   null;
end;
```

And all functions implemented as something like:

```
begin
   return The_Return_Type'first; --'
end;
```

As for separates...I don't like them. For me I'd much rather be able to follow the rule that all the code for a package is in its package body. Separates are marginally acceptable if for some reason the routine is *huge*, but in that case a better solution is almost always to refactor your code. So any time I see one, it is a big red flag.

As for the file name thing, this is a gnat issue, not an Ada issue. Gnat took the unusual position for a compiler that the name of the contents of a file dictate what the file itself must be named. There are probably other compilers in the world that do that, but I've yet to find one in 30 years of coding.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments. 1 vote up.